# Visual Studio Team System 2008 - messy formatting/control characters/marks in source code

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I don't know what I did but somehow the IDE has started displaying a green dot whenever I press spacebar and a green arrowhead whenever I press TAB. The source has become littered with these characters all over and I am finding it very difficult to code in the presence of so many formatting marks. I have tried to search a solution on Google but couldn't perhaps enter the right keywords so haven't been able to fix the behavior.

Is there any way I can stop VS2008 IDE from littering my source code with these green dots and arrowheads whenever I press spacebar/tab?

I would be really thankful for this help.

Thanks,

-AL

Answer (score 1):

Turn off "Edit/Advanced/View White Space"